# Make a label support Multi-lang in one string

Tags: c#, localization

I have a treeview and when I select a tree node which has a path in Arabic and English the output is displayed wrong:

***Code***

```
lbl_path.Text = treeView1.SelectedNode.FullPath;
```

[image]

The correct path would be `"ewae/test/اصناف جديده/تجربه 2 /main/"`

How can I format the path correct?

Comment: Can you post the code you are using to display the path.

Comment: this is my code 'lbl_path.Text = treeView1.SelectedNode.FullPath;'